# Convert JavaPairRdd to JavaRdd by concatenating key and value

Tags: java, apache-spark, concatenation, rdd

I am new to Apache Spark. As the title says, I have a `JavaPairRdd<String,String>` and I want to produce a `JavaRdd<String>` with the concatenation of the key and the value of the `JavaPairRdd`. Is this possible?

Example:

```
("1,Nick", "mail@sth.com,53")
("2,John", "mail@sth.com,53")
```

Result (`JavaRdd<String>` with):

```
"1,Nick,mail@sth.com,53"
"2,John,mail@sth.com,53"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `map`:

```
pairRDD.map((key, value) => key + value)
```

That is using scala, but you should get the gist.